# Add text above TextFormField using InputDecoration

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I want to place a text on top of `TextFormField` using the `InputDecoration` built-in decorations.

The `InputDecoration` provides several options such as `helperText`, `labelText`, and so on... But no none of them is capable of positioning the text above the form.

Here is what I'm looking for:

[image]

As you can see, The `Email` label should appear above the `TextFormField`.

*I'm not looking for `Column` solutions.

Comment: you cannot change the positions, they are fixed

Comment: Have you try using `ListTile` instead of `Column`? and I think the pskink is correct.